# How to reset the SQLite in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want that my users can resett the aplicatiom, then I need to reset the sqlite database that I have created. I'm using "context.deleteDatabase("***");" and calling the method tahr create the data base againg. 
The problem is: when I delet the database I have to close the app and open it to see the chages. If I dont close the app, I continue with the same database.

Answer (score 2):

to delete your app database try this:

```
 this.deleteDatabase("databasename.db");
```

the above statement will delete the db file.

Comment: Thats what I doing, deleting the file. The problem is that I have to close the app and open it to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

How about just dropping all the tables instead?

Comment: I ha 33 tables with some constraints. It would be so complicated.